# Exchange 2010 Meeting Room invitations to display Resource custom properties

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-web-app

With Exchange 2010 and Outlook 2013, How to display Meeting Room Resource Custom Properties (Capacity, TV, Phone etc...) in the invitation so that the recipients can view them in their invite.